# The simplest way to save a variable in the cloud, for discord bot

Tags: python, cloud, discord, bots, discord.py

I deployed a python bot of Discord on Heroku (Data is volatile) and works great, but I need storage a Log (variable boolean) and don't know a way simple to do it, I had tried with google drive and one drive but don't work or need constant manual authentication.

What is most simple way to do it or some direction that I can search for?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: MongoDB Atlas, or any other hosted database. Probably Heroku provides a managed database solutions themselves.

Comment: If all you need is a variable you can use `bot.variable_name`, a botvariable is available across `Cogs`. Alternatively if you're looking for a database you can rely on any service that provides a free tier (redis labs, mongo db etc)